# erlang library - export module from another directory than src (rebar3)

Tags: erlang, elixir, rebar3

In rebar3 erlang library I have two modules: `t1` and `t1` in `src` directory and `t3` module in `extras` directory. Now in `mylib.app.src` I'm trying to make them available outside library by:

```
{modules, [t1, t2, t3]}
```

I pointed that `extra` directory in `rebar3.config`:

```
{extra_src_dirs, ["extras"]}.
```

But still, I cannot use `t3` module in project, which uses this library. What else should I do to make this module available outside?

Comment: `"extra"` ≠ `"extras"` is it typo here or in your code?

Comment: sorry, its not in code, it is just example here, i changed it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `{src_dirs, ["extras"]}.`. Please refer to `rebar3` [documentation](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/configuration) for more information (`Directories`) section.

Also you do not need to include the modules in `mylib.app.src` manually. `rebar3` automatically adds all the source modules to the `mylib.app` file during compilation. The `.app` would be in `ebin` directory (`_build/default/lib/mylib/ebin/`).

Comment: What is the option for rlx when building for release?
The option "src_dirs" is not applicable in rlx conifgurations.